# Trying to access Dribbble API v1 with OAuth2 authentication

Tags: php, curl, dribbble-api

I'm trying to build a simple PHP script for my own using the new Dribbble API, which requires OAuth2.

The thing is, currently there isn't any PHP wrapper that covers their v1 API, and I'm struggling to build a cURL authentication system.  I tried to build a library with an authentication based on wrappers for other systems, like this [Instagram library](https://github.com/cosenary/Instagram-PHP-API) and this [Twitter library](http://github.com/j7mbo/twitter-api-php), but to no avail.

Note that I need to have an authentication system, because I need `write` scope. Using Client Access Token only gives `public`/`read-only` scope.

The API documentation: http://developer.dribbble.com/v1/

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I did it with json -

```
<?php
    $perPage = 50; // how many you want to display
    $dribbble_username = 'yourusername'; // dribbble username
    $dribbble_access_token = 'youraccesstoken'; // access token
    $dribbble_data = file_get_contents("https://api.dribbble.com/v1/users/$dribbble_username/shots?access_token=$dribbble_access_token&per_page=$perPage");
    $dribbble = json_decode($dribbble_data, true);
    foreach($dribbble as $shot) : ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $shot['html_url'] ?>" target="_blank">
            <img src="<?php echo $shot['images']['hidpi'] ?>" alt="<?php echo $shot['title'] ?>">
        </a>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Remember to register your application to get the access token. After you get it going you can simpy put https://api.dribbble.com/v1/users/yourusername/shots?access_token=youraccesscode into the browser to see the array of contents you can play with. Good luck ;)

Comment: I thank you for this, but actually I need `write` scope. Client Access Token only gives access to endpoints with `public` scope. Updated question to clarify this, sorry.